# How to optimize images for mozilla and chrome

Tags: html, css, image, optimization, frontend

I am building a website and I have images for different categories, they are displayed normally in chrome (see the image below):

[image]

But, in mozilla, they are displayed like this:

[image]

My HTML and CSS code for this category card:

```css
.category-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 32%;
    -webkit-height:32%;
    -moz-height:32%;
}
.category-image:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
```

```html
<div class = "col-md-6">
  <div class = "category" align = "center">
    <h2 class = "category-header remove-margin-h">PS4 GAMES</h2>
    <a href = "xml/ps_igre.xml"><img class = "category-image" src = "ps-gaming.jpg"></a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how to optimize these images through css so they work on both browser as they should?

Comment: It looks like a conflict somewhere else in your code. Try to isolate the problem by making a jsFiddle. You don’t need browser prefixes for `height`

Comment: @Kokodoko ok, I'll try something, someone else got any solutions?